# How to set shm-size or /dev/shm for Cloud Run container?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to get a Selenium docker image running properly on Cloud Run, however I appear to have hit a wall.

While the following command works flawlessly on my localhost, I've not been able to get it working on Google's Cloud Platform.

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-edge:4.7.2-20221219
```

I've narrowed down the problem to the size of the shared memory /dev/shm allocation on the Cloud Run container, which I think is set to 64M by default. Is there a way to raise this to 2G?

I have configured my Cloud Run containers to have 4GB memory + 2 vCPUs.

Oh, I cannot run my Selenium instance headless for a bunch of reasons.

Your help is greatly appreciated.